# Solution for blur() on a select in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, focus

This is not working on Chrome?

```
<select id="mySelect" onmouseout="defocusSelect()">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
</select>
...
function defocusSelect(){
document.getElementById('mySelect').blur();
}
```

I need this in order to hide the options list when I move the mouse away from the select. It is not working in Chrome. Does anyone know what can I use instead of `blur()` in order to make this work on Chrome?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3348559/22470

Comment: Which version of chrome and which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my hack for this problem

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
        if(is_chrome) $(".option").hide();
```

where class "option" represent all the option of select box.

Here I have used jquery to hide you can use anything you like.